# How to make gRPC Calls with swift in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, grpc

I am trying to access some google cloud RPCs API's using https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift

What I am doing is very similar to the [Natural Language Example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/tree/nio/Examples/Google/NaturalLanguage).
I was able to get a version working with the version 0.10.0 off the master branch, but readme says this branch is deprecated and the 'nio' branch should be used.
Unfortunately the sample code is not in sync with the project and won't compile.  I did my best to fix the code, but I cannot get it to work.

```
class NaturalLanguageRPCTests {
    let authToken : String
    var service : Google_Cloud_Language_V1_LanguageServiceServiceClient?
    var clientConnection : ClientConnection?
    let eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)

    init(authToken: String) {
        self.authToken = authToken
    }

    func createService() {
        let host = "language.googleapis.com"
        let port = 443

        let tls = ClientConnection.Configuration.TLS(configuration: TLSConfiguration.forClient(applicationProtocols: ["h2"]))
        let configuration = ClientConnection.Configuration(target: .hostAndPort(host, port),
                                                           eventLoopGroup: self.eventLoopGroup,
                                                           errorDelegate: self,
                                                           connectivityStateDelegate: self,
                                                           tls: tls)
                                                           //connectionBackoff: ConnectionBackoff?)
        self.clientConnection = ClientConnection(configuration: configuration)
    }



    func makeRPCCall() {
        guard let connection = self.clientConnection, connection.connectivity.state == .ready else {
            fatalError()
        }
        if self.service == nil {
            self.service = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_LanguageServiceServiceClient(connection: connection)
        }
        guard let service = self.service else {
            print("SERVICE HASN'T BEEN CREATED YET")
            return
        }
        // Use CallOptions to send the auth token (necessary) and set a custom timeout (optional).
        let http_headers = HTTPHeaders([("authorization", "Bearer " + self.authToken)])
        let headers = HPACKHeaders(httpHeaders: http_headers)
        let timeout = try! GRPCTimeout.seconds(30)
        let callOptions = CallOptions(customMetadata: headers, timeout: timeout)
        print("CALL OPTIONS\n\(callOptions)\n")

        // Construct the API request.
        var document = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_Document()
        document.type = .plainText
        document.content = "The Caterpillar and Alice looked at each other for some time in silence: at last the Caterpillar took the hookah out of its mouth, and addressed her in a languid, sleepy voice. `Who are you?' said the Caterpillar."

        var features = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_AnnotateTextRequest.Features()
        features.extractSyntax = true
        features.extractEntities = true
        features.extractDocumentSentiment = true
        features.extractEntitySentiment = true
        features.classifyText = true

        var request = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_AnnotateTextRequest()
        request.document = document
        request.features = features
        print("REQUEST MESSAGE\n\(request)")


        // Create/start the API call.
        let call = service.annotateText(request, callOptions: callOptions)
        call.response.whenSuccess { response in
            print("CALL SUCCEEDED WITH RESPONSE\n\(response)")
        }
        call.response.whenFailure { error in
            print("CALL FAILED WITH ERROR\n\(error)")
        }
        do {
            // wait() on the status to stop the program from exiting.
            let status = try call.status.wait()
            print("CALL STATUS\n\(status)")
        } catch {
            print("EXAMPLE FAILED WITH ERROR\n\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

When I call 
   `test.createService()` and monitor the status of the connection, it transitions to 'ready', so I assume the connection is being made.

But, when I call `test.makeRPCCall()` I get errors.
From the log:

```
2019-11-29T20:10:23-0800 info: path=/google.cloud.language.v1.LanguageService/AnnotateText 
request_id=0EAC0A92-2842-4D5A-BC94-B0BD4D6171EF starting rpc

CALL STATUS
unimplemented (12): invalid HTTP status: Not Found
2019-11-29T20:10:48-0800 info: duration_ms=46 request_id=0EAC0A92-2842-4D5A-BC94-B0BD4D6171EF status_code=12 rpc call finished
CALL FAILED WITH ERROR
unimplemented (12): invalid HTTP status: Not Found
```

I'm sure it is something simple I am doing wrong, but I can't get it working for the life of me.  If anyone has some insight into this, I would greatly appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: not sure about this repo but you could try this - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming. I'm planning to work on grpc soon.

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question.

1. There was a bug in grpc-swift which has been fixed.  Awesome
   response time by the devs there!!!  So you will have to grab the
   latest from the nio branch as there isn't a release with the fix
   yet.
2. Here is the working code

   ```
   class NaturalLanguageRPCTests {
   let authToken : String
   var service : Google_Cloud_Language_V1_LanguageServiceServiceClient?
   var clientConnection : ClientConnection?
   let eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)

   init(authToken: String) {
       self.authToken = authToken
   }

   func createService() {
       let host = "language.googleapis.com"
       let port = 443

       let configuration = ClientConnection.Configuration(
           target: .hostAndPort(host, port),
           eventLoopGroup: eventLoopGroup,
           tls: .init()
       )
       self.clientConnection = ClientConnection(configuration: configuration)
   }

   func makeRPCCall() {
       guard let connection = self.clientConnection, connection.connectivity.state == .ready else {
           fatalError()
       }
       if self.service == nil {
           self.service = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_LanguageServiceServiceClient(connection: connection)
       }
       guard let service = self.service else {
           print("SERVICE HASN'T BEEN CREATED YET")
           return
       }
       // Use CallOptions to send the auth token (necessary) and set a custom timeout (optional).
       let headers: HPACKHeaders = ["authorization": "Bearer \(authToken)"]
       let callOptions = CallOptions(customMetadata: headers, timeout: .seconds(rounding: 30))
       print("CALL OPTIONS\n\(callOptions)\n")

       // Construct the API request.
       var document = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_Document()
       document.type = .plainText
       document.content = "The Caterpillar and Alice looked at each other for some time in silence: at last the Caterpillar took the hookah out of its mouth, and addressed her in a languid, sleepy voice. `Who are you?' said the Caterpillar."

       var features = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_AnnotateTextRequest.Features()
       features.extractSyntax = true
       features.extractEntities = true
       features.extractDocumentSentiment = true
       features.extractEntitySentiment = true
       features.classifyText = true

       var request = Google_Cloud_Language_V1_AnnotateTextRequest()
       request.document = document
       request.features = features
       print("REQUEST MESSAGE\n\(request)")


       // Create/start the API call.
       let call = service.annotateText(request, callOptions: callOptions)
       call.response.whenSuccess { response in
           print("CALL SUCCEEDED WITH RESPONSE\n\(response)")
       }
       call.response.whenFailure { error in
           print("CALL FAILED WITH ERROR\n\(error)")
       }
       do {
           // wait() on the status to stop the program from exiting.
           let status = try call.status.wait()
           print("CALL STATUS\n\(status)")
       } catch {
           print("EXAMPLE FAILED WITH ERROR\n\(error)")
       }
   }}
   ```